# Application crashes while opening a report wizard without visual studio

Tags: wpf

In my project Report wizard is using.But when tried to open the rdlc report from a machine which do not have visual studio application crashes.We can open the report after installing visual studio.Please help me

Comment: Most likely you have to install Crystalreports Runtime on your machines. [Here](http://tektutorialshub.com/how-to-download-and-install-crystal-report-runtime/) a Tutorial

Comment: Thanks lokusking. I have installed crystalReports. But still it is not working.